# Site does not load index styles after redirect from logout button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have
index.php (got login form)

login.php (login script)

home.php (main site)

logout.php (simple destroy and header to index.php)

my problem is that when i press my button in home.php that sends me to logout.php and then further on to index.php it does not load my Styles in index.php but just gives me a styleless index.php page unless i reload manually

in home.php i got: (REMOVED SCRIPTS AS THERE IS A LOT OF STUFF THERE)

```html
<?php


session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
 header("location: index.php");
}

    
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>MY WEBSITE PAGE</title>
<style>
body {
    background-color: #1B1F2A;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 color:white;
}

.pageone { 
 color:white;
 background-color:white;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 background: #092756;
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%),-moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%, rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%, #092756 100%);
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
 background: -o-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
 background: -ms-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), linear-gradient(135deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3E1D6D', endColorstr='#092756',GradientType=1 );
}

.td{
 color:white;
}

.th{
 color:white;
}
 
.widget {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:15%;
    margin-top:50px;
    background-color: #222D3A;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #06060d;
 
}

#myStyle{
 color:white;
}

#willitwork2{
 color:white;
}
 
.header{
    background-color: #29384D;
    height:40px;
    color:#929DAF;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #06060d;
}

#chartContainer{
 <!--position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 width:80%;
 height:80%; -->
 width: 75%;
 position: fixed;
 left: 47%;
 top: 15%;
 margin-left: -37.5%;
 
}
 
.chart-container{
    padding:0px;
}

canvas{
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
  color: #ffffff;
    }
 
.shadow {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5) );
    filter: drop-shadow( 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5) );
}


</style>
<!--<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheets/normalize.css'>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

<link href="restive.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  

  
<div data-role="page" id="pageone" class="pageone">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Bar & Tap Concept</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
  
    <div id="myStyle" style="margin: 0 auto; display: table;">
 <table id="people" border="0">
 <thead>
 <th colspan='11'>10 Latest Dispenses</th>
 </thead>
  <thead>
    <th>MasterNo.</th>
 <th>PourDatetime</th>
 <!--<th>PLU</th>-->
 <!--<th>Volume</th>-->
   <!-- <th>ReceiveDatetime</th> -->
  <!--<th>DeviceID</th>-->
    <th>size</th>
 <!--<th>arm</th>-->
 <!--<th>Rack</th>-->
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Department</th>
 <th>Price</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>

</div>
<div id="willitwork2">
 <table id="informations" border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
            <th>Informations</th>                      
        </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div id='chartContainer'>
 <canvas id='myChart'>we</canvas>  
</div>
  <!-- this is the bottom menu dont ruin -->
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onClick="recp('1')" data-icon="plus">More</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onClick="recp('2')" data-icon="minus">Less</a></li>    
        <li><a href="#" onClick="recp('3')" data-icon="check">Like</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onClick="recp('4')" data-icon="info">Information</a></li>
  <li><a href="logout.php" data-icon="delete">Log Out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

in logout.php i got:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
$home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/index.php';
header('Location: ' . $home_url);
```

in index.php i got:

```html
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
header("location: home.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Login Form</title>
        <style>
      /* NOTE: The styles were added inline because Prefixfree needs access to your styles and they must be inlined if they are on local disk! */
      @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
.btn { display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; padding: 4px 10px 4px; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; color: #333333; text-align: center;text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); vertical-align: middle; background-color: #f5f5f5; background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#e6e6e6)); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-repeat: repeat-x; filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffff, endColorstr=#e6e6e6, GradientType=0); border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6; border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); border: 1px solid #e6e6e6; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); cursor: pointer; *margin-left: .3em; }
.btn:hover, .btn:active, .btn.active, .btn.disabled, .btn[disabled] { background-color: #e6e6e6; }
.btn-large { padding: 9px 14px; font-size: 15px; line-height: normal; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; }
.btn:hover { color: #333333; text-decoration: none; background-color: #e6e6e6; background-position: 0 -15px; -webkit-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; -moz-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; -ms-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; -o-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; transition: background-position 0.1s linear; }
.btn-primary, .btn-primary:hover { text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); color: #ffffff; }
.btn-primary.active { color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); }
.btn-primary { background-color: #4a77d4; background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#6eb6de), to(#4a77d4)); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-repeat: repeat-x; filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#6eb6de, endColorstr=#4a77d4, GradientType=0);  border: 1px solid #3762bc; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .btn-primary.disabled, .btn-primary[disabled] { filter: none; background-color: #4a77d4; }
.btn-block { width: 100%; display:block; }

* { -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -ms-box-sizing:border-box; -o-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box; }

html { width: 100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; }
  
body { 
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 background: #092756;
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%),-moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%, rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%, #092756 100%);
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
 background: -o-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
 background: -ms-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), linear-gradient(135deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3E1D6D', endColorstr='#092756',GradientType=1 );
}
.login { 
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
}
.login h1 { color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); letter-spacing:1px; text-align:center; }

input { 
 width: 100%; 
 margin-bottom: 10px; 
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 border-radius: 4px;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 45px rgba(100,100,100,0.2), 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
 -webkit-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
 -moz-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
 -o-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
 -ms-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
 transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
}
input:focus { box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 45px rgba(100,100,100,0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2); }
    </style> 
        <script src='js/prefixfree.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
   $("#submit").click(function(){
    
    var email = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    if( email =='' || password ==''){
     
    }
    else
    {
     $.post("login.php",{ email1: email, password1:password},
     function(data) {
      if(data=='Invalid Email.......') {
        $('input[type="text"]').css({"border":"2px solid red","box-shadow":"0 0 3px red"});
        $('input[type="password"]').css({"border":"2px solid #00F5FF","box-shadow":"0 0 5px #00F5FF"});
        alert(data);
      }else if(data=='Email or Password is wrong...!!!!'){
        $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css({"border":"2px solid red","box-shadow":"0 0 3px red"});
        alert(data);
      } else if(data=='Successfully Logged in...'){            
        alert(data);
      } else{        
        location.reload();
      }
     });
    }
   });
  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='login' id='login'>
 <h1>Login</h1>
    <form method="post" action="#">
     <input type="text" name="u" id="username" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
        <input type="password" name="p" id="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Let me in.</button>
    </form>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

home

Comment: Share your complete home.php file code

Comment: added my full home without scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed it using javascript function to redirect me to my logout.php

i think it has something to do with the way i implemented that my site reloads part of it inside.. anyway did this:

```
function recp(id) { 
  if(id == 4){
       alert(id);
       $('#myChart').show();      
       $('#myStyle').load('functions.php?id=' + id); 
  }else if(id == 5){ 
  window.location.href = "logout.php";
  }else{
      $('#myChart').hide();
      $('#myStyle').load('functions.php?id=' + id); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `redirect($home_url);` instead of `header()` may be solve your problem

Comment: what did the console said?404 or 503 or something else?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.. its like my index is getting loaded inside my logout page ...